# Oracle SQL Any comparision with subquery raises right paranthesis missing error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The query works fine with any operator for multiple values for any comparison.

```
SELECT Name, ID     
    from tblABC 
    where ID = ANY (1,2,3,4,5 )
```

But when a subquery is used for any comparison a right parenthesis missing error occurs

```
SELECT Name, ID     
    from tblABC 
    where ID = ANY (select ID from tblXYZ where ROWNUM <= 10 order by ID desc )
```

The subquery just gives the top 10 recent id entries from the selected table. Should there be a conversion to number or missing condition in this query?

Comment: The same issue with ```IN``` . Statement works fine with MySQL but not with Oracle PLSQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, [subquery is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-72CA75A4-AE94-471E-993F-20B969DB933F) and works fine in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=572e9f901f96e1b9b816203465019cb5). The reason is `order by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `order by`, which is not necessary as it is evaluated **after** `count stopkey` (which is `rownum < <constant>`).

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE'));
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                        |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:                                                 |
> | ------------------------                                                 |
> | select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ * from t where rownum < 5 order by  |
> | 1 asc                                                                    |
> |                                                                          |
> | Plan hash value: 846588679                                               |
> |                                                                          |
> | ------------------------------------                                     |
> | | Id  | Operation           | Name |                                     |
> | ------------------------------------                                     |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |                                     |
> | |   1 |  SORT ORDER BY      |      |                                     |
> | |*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY     |      |                                     |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |                                     |
> | ------------------------------------                                     |
> |                                                                          |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                      |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                      |
> |                                                                          |
> |    2 - filter(ROWNUM<5)                                                  |
> |                                                                          |
> ```

If you are on Oracle 12C+, then you may use `fetch first`:

> ```
> select *
> from dual
> where 1 = any(select l from t order by 1 asc fetch first 4 rows only)
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

Or `row_number()` for older versions:

> ```
> select *
> from dual
> where 1 = any (
>   select l
>   from (
>     select l, row_number() over(order by l asc) as rn
>     from t
>   )
>   where rn < 5
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> | DUMMY |
> | :---- |
> | X     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c58b96816fa769cfceef97700bcb4cc3)*

Comment: An interesting part is that both `fetch first` and `row_number()` approaches show the same `window sort pushed rank` in the execution plan

Answer (score 2):

It is order by part. It is not supported within sub-queries like this.

Just remove it. You don't need it for comparison anyway.

```
SELECT Name, ID     
  from tblABC 
where ID = ANY (select ID from tblXYZ where ROWNUM <= 10 )
```

Comment: Removing the `ORDER BY` clause changes the semantic of the query. The OP needs to confirm the new query is equivalent for their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FETCH FIRST <n> ROWS ONLY` instead of using the old `ROWNUM` in the subquery.

For example:

```
SELECT Name, ID     
from tblABC 
where ID = ANY (select ID 
                from tblXYZ 
                order by ID desc 
                fetch first 10 rows only)
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f18a792bfbfbf864229df7b3bd7ddff).